# Displaying value from JSON if mixed content

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

Demo on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/bjNmNM) is not working, so wondering what I did wrong

#### HTML

```
<div class="taco">
  <h2>{{ taco.name }}</h2>
  <p>{{ taco.recipe }}</p>
</div>
```

#### JS - babel

```
data:{
  taco: []
},
created(){
  this.GetTacos();
},
methods: {
  GetTacos () {
    axios.get('http://taco-randomizer.herokuapp.com/random/?full-taco=true')
    .then(response => {
      let taco = response.data;
      this.taco = {
        name: taco.name,
        recipe: taco.recipe
      };
    })
  }
}
```

#### JSON - sample object

```
{"seasoning_url": null, "base_layer_url": "https://raw.github.com/sinker/tacofancy/master/base_layers/corn_blackbean.md", "shell_url": null, "slug": "chicken_verde_corn_and_black_bean_tacos_with_pico_de_gallo_and_salsa_de_aguacate", "condiment": {"url": "https://raw.github.com/sinker/tacofancy/master/condiments/salsa_de_aguacate.md", "slug": "salsa_de_aguacate", "name": "Salsa de Aguacate", "recipe": "Salsa de Aguacate\n==========\n\nThis is the traditional green sauce served from a Mexican taco cart. Very popular with Tacos al Past\u00f3r or Tacos de Canasta, it is a creamy, green sauce. It has avacado, but it by no means a guacamole. Usually available with other taco cart staples such as: sliced radishes, spicy salsa roja, fresh cilantro, and fresh limes.\n\n* 1/2 Kilo of Green Tomatillos (~1lb.)\n* 2 green Serrano peppers (optional for heat)\n* 1 avocado\n* 2 limes\n* 1/2 cup crema (Mexican sour cream, thinner and sweeter than standard sour cream)\n\nCook the tomatillos and peppers in a pot with water until soft. Drain the water out and let cool.\n\nPut tomatillos, peppers, salt, lime-juice, crema, and avacado (shelled and pitted) in blender. With lid on, blend until completely mixed and liquid consistency. Salsa should be the consistency of crema, liquid, yet slightly viscous.\n\nPour over your tacos liberally. Refrigerate between uses.\n\ntags: vegetarian\n"}, "condiment_url": "https://raw.github.com/sinker/tacofancy/master/condiments/salsa_de_aguacate.md", "recipe": "Chicken Verde, Corn and Black Bean Tacos with Pico de Gallo and Salsa de Aguacate\n=================================================================================\n\nThese are great tacos--full of a bunch of really wonderful, subtle, and complementary flavors that build into something just immensely eatable. \n\nTaco Objects to Assemble\n------------------------\n\n* [Slow-Cooked Salsa Verde Chicken](/base_layers/slow_cooked_salsa_verde_chicken.md)\n* [Corn & Blackbeans](/base_layers/corn_blackbean.md)\n* [Phoning it in Pico de Gallo](/condiments/Pico_de_gallo.md)\n* [Salsa de Aguacate](/condiments/salsa_de_aguacate.md)\n\nDirections\n----------\n\n1. Get that chicken into your slow cooker nice and early.\n2. Make everything else as the day progresses.\n3. Assemble everything on a table.\n4. Build your tacos and eat.\n5. Feel incredibly full and happy.", "mixin_url": null, "url": "https://raw.github.com/sinker/tacofancy/master/full_tacos/chicken_corn_aguacate.md", "base_layer": {"url": "https://raw.github.com/sinker/tacofancy/master/base_layers/corn_blackbean.md", "slug": "corn_and_black_beans", "name": "Corn and Black Beans", "recipe": "Corn and Black Beans\n===================\n\nThis is a fork of the [Zuccini and Corn Filling](/base_layers/zucchini_corn.md) because I'm not a Zuccini fan. I also tweaked the spices.\n\nYou'll need:\n\n* Fresh corn kernels, cut off the cob.\n* 1 can of Black Beans\n* half a white onion\n* salt\n* chili powder\n* cumin\n\nDirections\n----------\n\n1. Toast corn in a skillet over high heat with oil and salt for about 5 minutes, or until browned. Remove corn.\n2. Cook onion in the skillet until it caramelizes (about 5 minutes). Leave onion in there.\n3. Add corn back in.\n4. Add black beans.\n5. Toss in a pinch of salt, a healthy couple shakes of chili powder, and a small pinch of cumin.\n6. Cook together for another 5 minute or so.\n\nDelicious hot as the main base_layer or as a supplement to others.\n\ntags: vegetarian, vegan\n"}, "name": "Chicken Verde, Corn and Black Bean Tacos with Pico de Gallo and Salsa de Aguacate"}
```

---

So that I don't have this same issue in the future I would appreciate a list of keywords to search further to study. So that I can get better at displaying data from APIs

Comment: I have tested your code, it worked, what is your issue?

Comment: @TamasSzoke in codepen? i don't see anything displayed

Comment: Found it, protocol error, use https.

Comment: @TamasSzoke wondering if i should delete this question or just reword it so it can be useful somehow?

Comment: I think it's okay, reminds to check the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/bjNmNM'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest
>   endpoint
>   'http://taco-randomizer.herokuapp.com/random/?full-taco=true'. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

So you should use https instead of http:

```
axios.get('https://taco-randomizer.herokuapp.com/random/?full-taco=true')
```

Always check the JavaScript console (ctrl+shift+j) for errors.

[Working codepen](https://codepen.io/Smoove7/pen/GBgPKg)

Comment: Also, the string for recipe in JSON was formatted but i need to convert that, any tips?

Comment: Try the vue directive called **v-html**. `<p v-html="taco.recipe"></p>` or check the source markdown script @ http://taco-randomizer.herokuapp.com